# Customizing Friendly_id URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-url, friendly-id

First I am sorry for my English

I am using Friendly_id gem to create Clean URL and it work just fine but instead of having a URL like this `http://localhost:3000/profile/jack-sparo` I want a URL like this `http://localhost:3000/profile/1/jack-sparo`where 1 is the user_id, so how can I do it?

this is my config/routes

```
  get "profiles/show" 

  get '/profile/:id' => 'profiles#show', :as => :profile
  get 'profiles' => 'profiles#index'
```

and this is my Profile controller

```
  def show
    @user= User.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    if @user
        @posts= Post.all
        render action: :show
    else
        render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end
  end
```

Comment: post your config/routes.rb and I can give you exact code, it depends on your current routes though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `id` of the record in URL anyway, you don't need
Friendly_id gem. You need to tune routes.

But maybe you would be happy with something like this instead?

```
http://localhost:3000/profiles/1-john-smith
```

If so, you need to override `to_param` method in `User` model like
this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name}".parameterize
  end
end
```

Now the `profile_path(profile)` helper will generate URL like

```
http://localhost:3000/profiles/1-john-smith
```

And, with this request, the `User.find(params[:id])` in controller
will find profile with id `1` and cut all other stuff which was in URL.

So

```
http://localhost:3000/profiles/1-mojombo-smith
```

will link to the same profile as

```
http://localhost:3000/profiles/1-john-smith
```

Comment: the con of this approach is i can still access to the profile just with the user_id like this profiles/1 or profiles/1-somes-words

Comment: Otherwise, you'll have to parse name from URL to database-friendly
format to be able to search with `first_name` and `last_name` and `id`
together. Looks like a bit over-complicated.